# Several photos in recyclerview item

Tags: android, kotlin

I wont to display many images in recyclerview item nicely like in facebook or over social network.

[image]
Is it some solutions like libraries for this. I have ideas how do something like this, but may be it some ready-made?

Comment: https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to get these images from the web you can use a library called picasso, it's simple to setup and use.

just add the dependency line to the build.gradle:

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

and use it like that:

Picasso.get().load("put url img here").fit().into(imageView);

Comment: I am using glide, thanks. Question is not about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use StaggeredGridLayoutManager as the Layout Manager in RecyclerView.
Ex: https://www.android4dev.com/how-to-use-recyclerview-with-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-android-kotlin/

And if you're loading these images online you can use a third-party library like Picasso.

Comment: It is looks interesting, but it looks like i have to use recyclerview inside recyclerview, is it normal? I mean what there is recyclerview, which content posts. If it images in post, I want to show this in something like straggeredgrid. Is it correct construction?

Comment: Why do you want to go ahead with recyclerview inside recyclerview? Not sure about it? Are you going to images and something else as well?

Comment: I sow straggededgrid. It structure like recyclerview

Comment: Hi, It works, but not in way I wonted. First, It may not show all pictures, or show it some unpredictable.  I see it dependence of spanCount and pictures count. Is it way to set it fo correct work?

Comment: I thought, what spanCount is a maximum row number, but it is not(